# Pull in the page path with Referrer variable in GTM?

Tags: variables, google-tag-manager, referrer

I am trying to collect the referrer URL in Google Tag Manager and I want it to include the referring path page. I want to do this because I have multiple links from the same domain pointing to one form. I want to track which page is bringing in the most form fills and so that I can trigger an email series based on which landing page they came from.

For example, I have 3 landing pages directing to one of my forms:

1. [www.site1.com/first-page-path](http://www.site1.com/first-page-path)
2. [www.site1.com/second-page-path](http://www.site1.com/second-page-path)
3. [www.site1.com/third-page-path](http://www.site1.com/third-page-path)

When I check the referrer variable in Google Tag Manager, it simply displays the domain name as follows:

`referrer: https://www.site1.com/`

How do I collect the the full URL including the page path so that it shows up like this:

`referrer: https://www.site1.com/second-page-path`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's limit by the [referrer policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy). These days, browsers usually set very restrictive defaults for the referrer policies, so only the referring domain is sent.

If you can manage the other domain or you can give each page with different form url.

You can add some parameter at the form url and add proper setting in GTM to retrieve it.

In general, referrer has always been a bit unreliable, and is now so limited that you probably should not use it for business critical purposes.